# The signal signal_switch_page() does not work

Tags: c++, gtkmm, gtkmm3

Hello I have a problem using the library Gtkmm. I have define a

```
Gtk::Notebook notebook;
```

but I have a problem with the signal

```
notebook.signal_switch_page().connect([this](){
std::cout << "It works !" << std::endl;
});
```

actually this signal does not work. Any suggestions ?

Comment: How does it "not work". Do you get an error message, crash you computer or does nothing! Check out [mcve] to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

[signal_switch_page](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/3.20/classGtk_1_1Notebook.html#ac3cbcfaab1f66313e1988def8bec0432)'s prototype is `void on_my_switch_page(Widget* page, guint page_number)` so the correct syntax is:

```
notebook.signal_switch_page().connect([this](Gtk::Widget* page, guint page_number){
            std::cout << "It works !" << std::endl;
        });
```

Comment: I'm also pretty sure it was already answered on SO but can't find the question now.